# How can I find clicked div element from class id using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe with AI capabilities.
Here is the full code.

```
const statusDisplay = document.querySelector('.game--status');

let gameActive = true;
let currentPlayer = "X";
let gameState = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

let winingScores = {
    X: 10,
    O: -10,
    tie: 0
};

const winningMessage = () => `Player ${currentPlayer} has won!`;
const drawMessage = () => `Game ended in a draw!`;
const currentPlayerTurn = () => `It's ${currentPlayer}'s turn`;

statusDisplay.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();

const winningConditions = [
    // Horizontal wins
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    // Vertical wins
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    // Diagonal wins
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];

function handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex) {
    gameState[clickedCellIndex] = currentPlayer;
    clickedCell.innerHTML = currentPlayer;
}

function handlePlayerChange() {
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    statusDisplay.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();
}

function handleResultValidation() {
    let roundWon = false;
    for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
        let a = gameState[winCondition[0]];
        let b = gameState[winCondition[1]];
        let c = gameState[winCondition[2]];
        if (a === '' || b === '' || c === '') {
            continue;
        }
        if (a === b && b === c) {
            roundWon = true;
            break
        }
    }

    if (roundWon) {
        statusDisplay.innerHTML = winningMessage();
        gameActive = false;
        return;
    }

    let roundDraw = !gameState.includes("");
    if (roundDraw) {
        statusDisplay.innerHTML = drawMessage();
        gameActive = false;
        return;
    }

    handlePlayerChange();
}

function handleCellClick(clickedCellEvent) {
    if(currentPlayer === "X"){
        const clickedCell = clickedCellEvent.target;
        const clickedCellIndex = parseInt(clickedCell.getAttribute('data-cell-index'));

        if (gameState[clickedCellIndex] !== "" || !gameActive) {
            return;
        }

        handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex);
        handleResultValidation();
    }
    else{
        const clickedCellIndex = bestMoveForAI();
        const clickedCell = 

        handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex);
        handleResultValidation();
    }

}

function handleRestartGame() {
    gameActive = true;
    currentPlayer = "X";
    gameState = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    statusDisplay.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();
    document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => cell.innerHTML = "");
}

function bestMoveForAI(){
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    let bestMove = -1;
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        if(shadowGameState[i] === ""){
            shadowGameState[i] = "O";
            let score = minimax(gameState,0, false);
            gameState[i] = "";
            if(score > bestScore){
                bestScore = score;
                bestMove = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return bestMove;
}

function minimax(gameState, depth, isMaximizing){
    // check for AI win as "O" only
    let result = checkWinner();
    if (result !== null) {
      return winingScores[result];
    }

    if(isMaximizing===false){
        for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(gameState[i] === ""){
                gameState = "O";
                let score = minimax(gameState, depth + 1, false);
                gameState = "";
                bestScore = max(score, bestScore);
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
    
}

function checkWinner(){
    let winner;
    for(let i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
        const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
        let a = gameState[winCondition[0]];
        let b = gameState[winCondition[1]];
        let c = gameState[winCondition[2]];
        if(a === '' || b === '' || c === ''){
            continue;
        }
        if(a === b && b === c){
            winner = a;
            break;
        }
    }
    return winner;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', handleCellClick));
document.querySelector('.game--restart').addEventListener('click', handleRestartGame);
```

Human player (in this case first player with "X") can click a cell and javascript update the value of the game state and the cell in question.

For AI player's (in this case second player with "O") move, I am finding the best move and then updating the game state accordingly. But I don't know how to update the cell according to the best move.

Can anyone please help me ?

This is the function I am stuck at:

```
function handleCellClick(clickedCellEvent) {
if(currentPlayer === "X"){
    const clickedCell = clickedCellEvent.target;
    const clickedCellIndex = parseInt(clickedCell.getAttribute('data-cell-index'));

    if (gameState[clickedCellIndex] !== "" || !gameActive) {
        return;
    }

    handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex);
    handleResultValidation();
}
else{
    const clickedCellIndex = bestMoveForAI();
    const clickedCell = // how to find the clickedCell based on clickedCellIndex ?

    handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex);
    handleResultValidation();
}}
```

I know the index of clickedCell. I want to find the clickedCell , so that I can show "O" in the clickedCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query elements by the attribute. For example, for index 0, you could:

```
const clickedCell = document.querySelector('[data-cell-index="0"]');
```

Or in your case:

```
const clickedCell = document.querySelector(`[data-cell-index="${clickedCellIndex}"]`);
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping that the AI player's best move will be displayed similar to a Human player's move is displayed when a cell is clicked by a Human. I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: @shantanurahut oh your question was very clear, you just wanted to find the clickedCell give an index. To show something in it once you find it (with the answer above or similar approach), you can just `clickedCell.innerHTML = "O";`. Does it make sense?